# How to create an Image/avatar uploader for admin user

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, image-upload

I want to add a avatar image upload field for admin users.

I want when you go to system > permissions > users, and click the "Add New User" button, a image upload section is within the add new user form.[image]

My plan is to use the following code to create a new column in the "admin_user" database table, to store the image link.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin_user'),'avatar', 'varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "0"');
```

This would then make it easy to call and display said image wherever i need to.

```
$this->getUser()->getAvatar()
```

The issue is, i dont know how to add a image uploader and have it generate a link and place it in the database field.

Please provide as much info as possible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 26/07/2015:**
With the help provided in the accepted answer, I was able to create a module that provide some of the features I need. I see that the image uploader is now shown in the form, the image name is saved to the database, but unfortunately, I don't see the image in the media folder. Could someone help me to solve this last section please?

Please find the code used in accepted answer below.

Comment: please check permission of newly created "avatar" folder it should be 777

Comment: @amit_game it is 777

Comment: I edited my code now, please check it. I added a tag line in **config.xml** and you have to add a new file, which i have defined in my edited section. have fun. cheers :)

Comment: Can anybody check this, I am stuck   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195633/cant-access-images-on-pub-media-magento-2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You Need to override core magento code here - 
here we have generated a custom module which will do this and override the core functionality - 
Namespace - "A2bizz"

Generate below Directory Paths and their corresponding files and put the given code in it -

```
/app/etc/modules/A2bizz_All.xml
```

```
<config>
    <modules>        
         <A2bizz_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>            
        </A2bizz_Adminhtml>                
    </modules>
</config>
```

```
/app/code/local/a2bizz/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml
```

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <A2bizz_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </A2bizz_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <a2bizz_adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">A2bizz_Adminhtml</a2bizz_adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>         
    </admin>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <permissions_user_edit_tab_main>A2bizz_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main</permissions_user_edit_tab_main>
                    <permissions_user_edit_form>A2bizz_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Form</permissions_user_edit_form>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>    
</config>
```

```
/app/code/local/a2bizz/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/User/Edit/Tab/Main.php
```

```
<?php

class A2bizz_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('permissions_user');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('user_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Account Information')));

        if ($model->getUserId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('user_id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'user_id',
            ));
        } else {
            if (! $model->hasData('is_active')) {
                $model->setIsActive(1);
            }
        }

        $fieldset->addField('username', 'text', array(
            'name'  => 'username',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
            'id'    => 'username',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('firstname', 'text', array(
            'name'  => 'firstname',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('First Name'),
            'id'    => 'firstname',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('First Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('lastname', 'text', array(
            'name'  => 'lastname',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Name'),
            'id'    => 'lastname',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
            'name'  => 'email',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Email'),
            'id'    => 'customer_email',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Email'),
            'class' => 'required-entry validate-email',
            'required' => true,
        ));

        // ========================= Additional Field ========================
        $fieldset->addField('avatar', 'file', array(
            'name'  => 'avatar',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Avatar'),
            'id'    => 'customer_avatar',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Avatar'),            
            'required' => false,
        ));

        // ========================= Additional Field ========================

        $fieldset->addField('current_password', 'obscure', array(
            'name'  => 'current_password',
            'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Current Admin Password'),
            'id'    => 'current_password',
            'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Current Admin Password'),
            'class' => 'input-text',
            'required' => true,
        ));

        if ($model->getUserId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
                'name'  => 'new_password',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Password'),
                'id'    => 'new_pass',
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Password'),
                'class' => 'input-text validate-admin-password',
            ));

            $fieldset->addField('confirmation', 'password', array(
                'name'  => 'password_confirmation',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
                'id'    => 'confirmation',
                'class' => 'input-text validate-cpassword',
            ));
        }
        else {
           $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
                'name'  => 'password',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password'),
                'id'    => 'customer_pass',
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password'),
                'class' => 'input-text required-entry validate-admin-password',
                'required' => true,
            ));
           $fieldset->addField('confirmation', 'password', array(
                'name'  => 'password_confirmation',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
                'id'    => 'confirmation',
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
                'class' => 'input-text required-entry validate-cpassword',
                'required' => true,
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId() != $model->getUserId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('is_active', 'select', array(
                'name'      => 'is_active',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('This account is'),
                'id'        => 'is_active',
                'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Account Status'),
                'class'     => 'input-select',
                'style'        => 'width: 80px',
                'options'    => array('1' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Active'), '0' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Inactive')),
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('user_roles', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'user_roles',
            'id'   => '_user_roles',
        ));

        $data = $model->getData();

        unset($data['password']);

        $form->setValues($data);

        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

```
/app/code/local/a2bizz/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php
```

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'Permissions'.DS.'UserController.php'; 
class A2bizz_Adminhtml_Permissions_UserController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function saveAction()
    {        
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            //================== Avatar Save Code ======================
            if(isset($_FILES['avatar']['name']) && $_FILES['avatar']['name'] != '') {
                try {   
                    /* Starting upload */   
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('avatar');

                    // Any extention would work
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                    // Set the file upload mode 
                    // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                    // true -> get the file in the product like folders 
                    //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    // We set media as the upload dir
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'avatar' .DS;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['avatar']['name'] );

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }

                //this way the name is saved in DB
                $data['avatar'] = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
            }

            //================== Avatar Save Code ==END====================


            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
            $model = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId() && $id) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('This user no longer exists.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

            //Validate current admin password
            $currentPassword = $this->getRequest()->getParam('current_password', null);
            $this->getRequest()->setParam('current_password', null);
            unset($data['current_password']);
            $result = $this->_validateCurrentPassword($currentPassword);

            $model->setData($data);

            /*
             * Unsetting new password and password confirmation if they are blank
             */
            if ($model->hasNewPassword() && $model->getNewPassword() === '') {
                $model->unsNewPassword();
            }
            if ($model->hasPasswordConfirmation() && $model->getPasswordConfirmation() === '') {
                $model->unsPasswordConfirmation();
            }

            if (!is_array($result)) {
                $result = $model->validate();
            }
            if (is_array($result)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUserData($data);
                foreach ($result as $message) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($message);
                }
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('_current' => true));
                return $this;
            }

            try {
                $model->save();
                if ( $uRoles = $this->getRequest()->getParam('roles', false) ) {
                    /*parse_str($uRoles, $uRoles);
                    $uRoles = array_keys($uRoles);*/
                    if ( 1 == sizeof($uRoles) ) {
                        $model->setRoleIds($uRoles)
                            ->setRoleUserId($model->getUserId())
                            ->saveRelations();
                    } else if ( sizeof($uRoles) > 1 ) {
                        //@FIXME: stupid fix of previous multi-roles logic.
                        //@TODO:  make proper DB upgrade in the future revisions.
                        $rs = array();
                        $rs[0] = $uRoles[0];
                        $model->setRoleIds( $rs )->setRoleUserId( $model->getUserId() )->saveRelations();
                    }
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The user has been saved.'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUserData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setUserData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('user_id' => $model->getUserId()));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Now create a directory named 'avatar' inside media folder and continue with your installer to generate field to your desired place.

Hope it will work for you.

**[EDITED]**

```
/app/code/local/a2bizz/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/User/Edit/Form.php
```

```
<?php
class A2bizz_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form', 
                                           'action' => $this->getData('action'), 
                                           'method' => 'post',
                                           'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                                           )
                                     );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I have followed the the steps, on my localhost I can see the avatar field, while when I uploaded online it wouldn't come up, what could be the problem, can you please help?

Comment: @Alyas, Please check inside media/avtar that the uploaded image is exist there, also check permission of avtar directory.