# Can't access images on pub/media magento 2

Tags: magento2

I created `sign up with avatar` module and it throws the `customer avatars` in 
`pub/media/customer` as an example:

> http//:www.domain.com/pub/media/customer/u/n/undefined.png

But in the mobile app, when I call this link to display the avatar, I always get 404 page.

I checked the `customer folder` and found `.htaccess` the file which denies accessing all files under this folder. I removed it but still get **404 page**.

What is wrong?

Comment: No answer !!!!!

Comment: hi, you got this solution?  i have same issue.

Comment: Yes, there is  .htaccess file in customer directory, remove it. try that and if not solved tell me which server you are working on.

Comment: yes there is a .htaccess file but  after removing it or after changing its perminitions to allow all i am still unable to access this folder. I am using magento on bitnami.

Comment: however on localhost after changing permissions in .htaccess file i access images placed in customers folder but i have no luck on live server. please help

Comment: Any ways thanks for your time. I have now resolve this issue by configuring .htaccess of server

Comment: Great to hear that..